# Error sending an email with PHP Mailer to multiple recipients vice one recipient

Tags: phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email to multiple recipients using PHPMailer.  I keep getting the error message : "Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Data not accepted.
SMTP server error:"

When I use only one (1) recipient the email goes through, no problem.  What am I doing wrong.

I'm using PHPMailer verson 5.2.4.  The PHP Configuration settings on the server that I am using are PHP Version PHP 5.5.

Do these combos have anything to do with the code not working?

Here is the code I am using:

```
require_once ('/home/website/public_html/123/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once ('/home/website/public_html/123/phpmailer/class.smtp.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = 'mail.website.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
$mail->Username = 'email@website.com';            
$mail->Password = 'password';                     

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            

$mail->From = 'me@website.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Me';

$mail->AddAddress('recipient1@website.com', 'Recipient 1');      

$mail->AddCC('recipient2@website.com', 'Recipient 2');
$mail->AddCC("$recipient3", 'Recipient 3');
$mail->AddCC('recipient4@website.com', 'Recipient 4');
$mail->AddCC(recipient5@website.com, 'Recipient 5');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;  

$mail->IsHTML(true);  

$mail->Subject = "email subject";   


$mail->Body    ="Test";

if(!$mail->Send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
```

Comment: This line `$mail->AddCC(recipient5@website.com, 'Recipient 5');` has to return you syntax error.

Comment: Thanks panther.  My original code does reflect: 

$mail->AddCC('recipient5@website.com', 'Recipient 5');  

I made this error when I wrote the question on this forum.